# Google DFA Reporting - Bad Request (400) Invalid ProfileID

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to use Double Click for Advertisers API (DFA). I've explored the "**Try it**" and tested the Api through google developers console and it works as expected. I was able to catch the Authorization token and perform get and post requests(via browser and programmatically). 
However when I try to do exactly the same, programmatically using the donet api 2.4, the Authentication Token that is generated doesn't allow me to do any requests, it always returns HTTP 400 Bad Request with the reason **Invalid ProfileID.**

I'm not sure if the **client_secrets.json** are correct, but I've created it using the same email account that has access to the reports.

```
{
  "installed": {

    "client_id": "<client_id>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "<project_id>",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "<secret>",
    "redirect_uris": [ "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", "http://localhost" ]
  }
}
```

I used the credentials code below:

```
private static readonly IEnumerable<string> scopes = new[] {
  DfareportingService.Scope.Dfareporting,
  DfareportingService.Scope.Dfatrafficking
};    
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                      scopes,
                        "dfa-user", CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore("DfaReporting.Samples")).Result;
```

The generated token gives me the following info:

```
{
 "issued_to": "<client_id>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "audience": "<client_id>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfareporting https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfatrafficking",
 "expires_in": 3073,
 "access_type": "offline"
}
```

The libraries I mentioned above are available on GitHub: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dfa-reporting-samples/tree/master/dotnet/v2.4

What am I missing?

Comment: where is the request that is failing?  you have only posted your authentication code this isn't enough to find your error.    Remember the user that authenticates must be the same as the user who owns the profile you are trying to request data for.

Comment: It has not the full code but, basically the service is the result of the method where I get the credentials. The request that gives the exception (bad request) it's the service.Reports.Run
`DfareportingService service = DfaReportingFactory.getInstance();

(...)  
            // Run the report.
            File file = service.Reports.Run(profileId, reportId).Execute()
`

Comment: do userprofiles.list first your trying to run a report for a profile the user doesn't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have set this up [correctly](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/reporting/getting_started).

1. You must have a DCM account. See [Advertisers/Agencies](https://www.doubleclickbygoogle.com/solutions/digital-marketing/) for signup information.
2. Your DCM account must be enabled for API Access. Contact your DoubleClick representative or the DCM support team for assistance. (dcm-support@google.com)
3. You must have a user profile with access to this account. Have your DCM account administrator create a user profile associated with this account.

It sounds to me that who ever you are trying to use to authenticate doesn't have access to the profile you are trying to request for.

**In response to comment:**

If you are using the .net client library I don't understand why you would be calling the following request manually as you have commented

```
https://www.googleapis.com/dfareporting/v2.4/userprofiles?access_token=<access token>
```

I also don't understand how if you are using the .Net client library and the following request could return invalid profile id when you aren't sending one.  It might return no profiles if the user doesn't have access to any.

```
service.UserProfiles.List().Execute();
```

This might return invalid profile id if the profile id you send it is well not valid.

```
service.UserProfiles.Get(profileId).Execute();
```

**Running reports**

To be able to run a report the user must have access to the profile and the report.   Your error message means that the user doesn't have access to that profile you need to either login with a user that has access or grant the user access.

```
service.Reports.Run(profileId,reportId).Execute();
```

Comment: By making a GET https://www.googleapis.com/dfareporting/v2.4/userprofiles?access_token=<access_token_from_donet> I got an empty profile list, which means that the credentials passed on client_secrets.json are not correclty linked to the DFA account I'm using.

How do I know that I setup the clients secrets correctly? I've followed the instructions in the documentation.

Created a project, enabled the API and created a secret.

Comment: No you got an empty profile list because the user doesn't have any profiles.   If the credentials where incorrect you would have gotten an error and not been able to call the API at all.

Comment: as for setting it up correctly check nr 2 and 3.  Make sure you have access.

Comment: I'll check your tips and edit my comment later. Also just to answer why am I testing it manually was to troubleshooting if my tokens were valid or not, since with dotnet api i only got the bad request.

Comment: `service.UserProfiles.List().Execute();` gives 0 results.

In my question I didn't put the profileID and ReportID in the code sample, but I have it there, they are the same I used to test on the "Try it API" on the Web.

Summary looks like my user doesn't have profiles. How do I had them then?

The email account I use to Log on DFA Backoffice it's the same I used to create a project, client secrets and enable api in developers console.

I don't understand how the profiles work at all.